# How to use Steamworks API before our game is on Steam?

Tags: steam

I'm part of a small team working on a game that we plan on distributing through Steam and integrating features which will utilize Steamworks API. We're not sure what the process is at the moment for how we can utilize Steamworks API without our game already being on Steam. Does anyone know where we need to start? I would imagine we will need an `appid` to be able to access Steamworks.

Is there a way that we can setup the game on Steam but not have it released until it's complete?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, go through Steam Direct. Get your app set up there, but don't make it public.

https://partner.steamgames.com/steamdirect