# Test Steam APIs without paying the fee

Tags: steam, steamworks, api

I'm an amateur hobby programmer, and I'd like to make a library for some Steam APIs like Steamworks or Steam Input. To do that, I'd need to be able to test Steam APIs, but the problem is I do not have the $100 needed to publish a game (where I live it's really a lot of money). In fact, I'm not even planning to publish a game there yet, I just need some way to test Steam APIs to be able to develop for it.

Is there any way to do that? Either officially or unofficially (alternative Steam API-compatible servers, for example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Steamworks API before our game is on steam?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/153729/176531) ?

Comment: The only answer to that is “Yes, go through Steam Direct” which — surprise, surprise — requires you to pay the fee; thus not answering my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Steamworks API before our game is on Steam?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153729/how-to-use-steamworks-api-before-our-game-is-on-steam)

Comment: You linked literally the same exact question as before, I already answered why it does not answer my question.